# SQL query to fetch IDs present only after a certain date

Tags: sql

Tables look like this :-

```
   Table A                         
------------------------         
  ID    |   C_Start_Date          
------------------------          
  1     |   2018-03-10                  
  2     |   2018-03-15                  



Table B

 ----------------------------
      ID     |  Invoice_Date
 ----------------------------
      1      |  2018-01-15
      1      |  2018-02-15
      1      |  2018-03-15
      2      |  2018-04-01
      2      |  2018-04-04
```

I have to fetch ONLY those Id's which have Invoice_Date later than their C_Start_Date.
For example, from the above table, the query should fetch only '2' as '1' has an entry in Table B with Invoice_Date earlier than its C_Start_Date.

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL-Server so which database are you using? Whats the expected result?

Comment: This is a trivial `JOIN`. Show what you tried.

Comment: The reason I added both the databases is because I just want to know the logic, query is immaterial.
The expected result is the Id - 2.

Comment: @Anshul Any SQL tutorial should explain how to do this. SO is not a programming school.

Comment: @Barmar Can you help me? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Show your best attempt, we'll help you fix it. We won't write it for you.

Comment: select * from A inner join B on A.id = b.id where b.invoice_date > c_start_date

This is what I have. But it is fetching the record with ID = 1 where Invoice_Date = '2018-03-15'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working query:

```js
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM A
WHERE ID NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.INVOICEDATE < A.STARTDATE)
```

Fiddle for you to play and try around -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kXXXJopWvsmHccdnPAgdmv/0

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requisites the below example will solve your problem (written in TSQL)

```
declare @TableA as table
(
   ID int not null
  ,C_Start_Date date not null
)

declare @TableB as table
(
   ID int not null
  ,Invoice_Date date not null
)

insert into @TableA
values
 (1,'2018-03-10')                 
,(2,'2018-03-15')

insert into @TableB
values
 (1,'2018-01-15')
,(1,'2018-02-15')
,(1,'2018-03-15')
,(2,'2018-04-01')
,(2,'2018-04-04')


select a.ID
from @TableA a
where not exists
(
    select * from @TableB b where b.ID = a.ID and b.Invoice_Date < a.C_Start_Date
)
```

while the same be achieved with `DISTINCT` and a simple `JOIN` I utilised `EXISTS` as it generaly performs better than aggregates and distincts..